# IIS: How to disable HTTP method TRACE?

Tags: http, iis, web-config, trace, http-verbs

I followed [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1220539.aspx), which led to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs/) to try to disable my website from accepting the TRACE method (verb). Basically I added the section below to `<system.webServer>` inside Web.config (Default Web Site and the other website):

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
       <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
          <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
       </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It didn´t work. Then I went to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and replaced all handlers' verb inside `<handlers>`. In a nutshell, all lines like this:

```
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```

Became this:

```
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```

I even restarted the server but when I check the available methods, TRACE is still there:

```
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS https://example.com/mysite
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Thu, 07 Feb 2019 21:03:49 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

So, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To truly block `TRACE` requests, you should still keep a request filtering rule with `TRACE` verb blocked.

The curl command sends an OPTIONS request to IIS, and the `ProtocolSupportModule` generates the response message,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview

However, Microsoft did not design any settings in `system.webServer/httpProtocol` section for you to change the value of the headers so as to hide `TRACE` from there.

But a workaround is to use URL Rewrite module,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/11/02/change-or-modify-a-response-header-value-using-url-rewrite/

where you create two outbound rules for `Allow` and `Public` headers,

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ChangeHeaders" stopProcessing="false">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Allow" pattern="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Public">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Public" pattern="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try that and let you know. One question though. Using this URL Rewrite module wouldn’t I just be masking the response header instead of actually disabling the HTTP verb TRACE?

Comment: To disable `TRACE` responses, you need the request filtering rule.

Comment: I have another website which its web.conf has <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> and <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /> under <handlers> and indeed it seems calling options or trace verbs on the website is not working. So, could maybe I remove these handlers from the applicationHost.config altogether?

Anyway, the way you suggested worked, I will mark this as answered.

Comment: I am not quite sure of your special setup, but generally speaking some handlers should remain in `applicationHost.config` in case your other sites need them. Like you found that removing the handlers via `web.config` is an alternative way, but you also lose the capability to define custom response headers.

Comment: Only this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case works:

```
 <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="HEAD" allowed="true" />
        <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
```

Please notice that I don't allow OPTIONS.
When I not allow OPTIONS then TRACE was also not allowed.