# Http TRACE does not implemented on IIS

Tags: http, web, iis, postman

I created a default web site on my local IIS and it works fine. After sending HTTP OPTIONS request I've noticed that TRACE verb is enabled. But there is impossible to inspect this verb, because IIS returns 501 - Not Implemented error. I don't completely understand why and how to enable TRACE verb for testing?

**OPTIONS**
[image]
**TRACE**
[image]

Comment: Have you got any code that implements a TRACE request handler, for example a controller? If no, what do you expect this call to do? There's probably some module or handler that reports to support TRACE for `/`, but it's not hit for the second request.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis FRT can tell you where that 501 comes from. Then you might know how to resolve it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, I haven't any controller for `OPTIONS` as well. But it works. As I understand IIS should handle this request themselve.

Comment: AFAIK, IIS handles OPTIONS requests by asking modules/handlers who can handle that. It doesn't implement it by itself. For example a CORS preflight, which is an OPTIONS request, needs to be handled by an application framework like ASP.NET.

Comment: @CodeCaster As I remember, if web-server got some TRACE request it should just return request without any changes. Not sure I need some controller for this. Especially because ASP.NET doesnt allow HttpTrace in code. [screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFD_bUevLUqZ9OusToIf94vDmErPJoNG/view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS responds with TRACE among others by default to an OPTIONS request, but doesn't support it out of the box. You can [remove it from the response entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582354/iis-how-to-disable-http-method-trace), let IIS perform it, or implement it yourself if you want to support it.

You can let IIS do it by [enabling the verb in Request Filtering (the reverse of what's shown at this link)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-track-and-trace-verbs/ba-p/784482).

It'll take something like a `[HttpMethod("TRACE")]` controller action if you want to do it yourself.

Comment: But that's very strange. TRACE response should be same as TRACE request. Isn't it? It sounds, like we don't need coding manually. Especially implement new attribute inherited from on HttpMethodAttribute

Comment: Do you want to hide TRACE, or support it? You usually want to hide it and not have it return a response.

Comment: I want to explore TRACE. I've seen a lot of solutions how to disable it, but never how to implement it in code.

Comment: I find conflicting/confusing information and barely any documentation online. Try enabling the verb explicitly in Request Filtering settings of your site, and see if IIS responds to it.

Comment: That is it! After adding a rule for TRACE in `Request Filtering` everything worked as expected. Thank you. [Screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xEBvuL-XYWoRwdgBD9XC_KVdxoSG8Y-E)