# Under IIS, I blocked HEAD,TRACE in request filtering, but it keeps appearing on the allowed methods list

Tags: .net, iis, iis-10

Under IIS, I blocked HEAD,TRACE in request filtering, but it keeps appearing on the allowed methods list.

[image: Allow methods]

[image: web.config file]

It works functionally but does not disappear from the allow method. I don't know why.

i want to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two outbound rules for the `Allow` and `Public` headers using the URL Rewrite module.

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ChangeHeaders" stopProcessing="false">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Allow" pattern="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="OPTIONS, GET, POST" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Public">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Public" pattern="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="OPTIONS, GET, POST" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

You can refer to Lex Li's answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582354/iis-how-to-disable-http-method-trace), hope it can help you!