# vulnerability with http IIS methods configuration

Tags: windows, http, security, iis, methods

I have a vulnerability about information disclosure with http IIS methods configuration and to solve it someone recommended me to disable the methods OPTIONS, TRACE and HEAD.Since , it was found  in port 8080 the supported methods: OPTIONS TRACE GET HEAD POST. How can i solve this vulnerability without affecting the server or the application because it's running. Is there another solution to solve this vulnerability?

[image: The problem]

[image: There is nothing in http verbs, Is there a possibility that the default methods are disabled and nothing needs to be done to fix the vulnerability?]

i am trying to disable those methods but they told me that i have to ensure this will solve the problem before i applied and i am not sure if this is the solution.I have to test in other server.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582354/iis-how-to-disable-http-method-trace

Comment: On your test server, disable the HTTP methods OPTIONS and TRACE and monitor the server's behavior.
In IIS, you can do this using the URL Rewrite module. Create rewrite rules to block requests using these methods.
But do not disable the GET and HEAD methods as they are essential for serving web content.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the HTTP methods OPTIONS, TRACE and HEAD does serve as a step towards mitigating information disclosure vulnerabilities. But it must be tested without impacting the production environment to ensure it does not negatively impact the functionality of the server or application.

Before making any changes, make sure you have a backup of your current server configuration. This is crucial if something goes wrong and you need to revert to a previous state.

Modify the server configuration to disable the OPTIONS, TRACE, and HEAD methods. This can usually be done in the IIS configuration file or through IIS Manager.

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <verbs>
         <remove verb="OPTIONS" />
         <remove verb="TRACE" />
         <remove verb="HEAD" />
       </verbs>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```